# Unable to get Grunt less task working on Custom Magento theme

Tags: configuration, custom-theme, less-css, grunt, less-compilation

Good morning,

I'm pretty new to Magento 2 and I'm currently in the process of trying to get my first custom M2 theme up and running.

I have managed to create my new theme but running into trouble when trying to get the Grunt LESS task running.

I have been following the Magento docs and do the following...

- added in the package.json, Gruntfile.js, and grunt-config.json files
- ran npm install && npm update
- I've then proceeded to add a local-themes.js file and update it to contain the following...

```
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

'use strict';

/**
* Define Themes
*
* area: area, one of (frontend|adminhtml|doc),
* name: theme name in format Vendor/theme-name,
* locale: locale,
* files: [
* 'css/styles-m',
* 'css/styles-l'
* ],
* dsl: dynamic stylesheet language (less|sass)
*
*/
module.exports = {
 blank: {
     area: 'frontend',
     name: 'Magento/blank',
     locale: 'en_US',
     files: [
         'css/styles-m',
         'css/styles-l',
         'css/email',
         'css/email-inline'
     ],
     dsl: 'less'
 },
 luma: {
     area: 'frontend',
     name: 'Magento/luma',
     locale: 'en_US',
     files: [
         'css/styles-m',
         'css/styles-l'
     ],
     dsl: 'less'
 },
 alpha: {
     area: 'frontend',
     name: 'SC/alpha',
     locale: 'en_GB',
     files: [
         'css/styles-m',
         'css/styles-l'
     ],
     dsl: 'less'
 },
 backend: {
     area: 'adminhtml',
     name: 'Magento/backend',
     locale: 'en_US',
     files: [
         'css/styles-old',
         'css/styles'
     ],
     dsl: 'less'
 }
};
```

My `grunt-config.json` is as follows...

```
{
    "themes": "dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes"
}
```

- Then when I try running the grunt exec:alpha command I get the following error...

```
Running "exec:alpha" (exec) task
Verifying property exec.alpha exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "exec.alpha" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Running the `grunt exec` command by itself references the blank and luma themes but not my custom theme.

Really not sure on how to proceed with this, has anyone else encountered this problem before?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to leave the default `themes.js` untouched and copy everything over to `local-themes.js` and add your own theme there.

Maybe also try using another name than "default" for the property.

Comment: Agreed, using default as a name may be causing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,

 I reverted the theme.js back to default and copied the contents over to local-theme.js and included my theme there. I've updated the theme name to be SC/alpha and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you post your full local-themes.js file? Maybe there's a problem in your json.
For example: Make sure that there's a comma after the } of the last default theme and before you add your theme

Comment: Hey @Chaz, Thanks for getting back to me. 

 I've updated my original question to include the full local-themes.js file contents.

Comment: I tried you local-themes.js file on my machine and I don't get the same error.
The full path to the file in your project is `dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js` right?
And If you run exec commands for the other themes they work?
Do other commands like clean work for your theme?

Comment: Hey @Chaz, sorry for the delayed response.

The grunt exec commands work for all other themes, just not my custom one. 

When running the grunt clean:alpha command I get the same error. 

Yeah the full path to the file in my project is dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js

Comment: I am running out of ideas here. I guess at this point I would probably copy over the files from the latest magento repository: package.json, Gruntfile.js, and grunt-config.json
or even the whole grunt directory in dev/tools/ and/or basically rerun the whole process described in the Magento docs, checking for mistakes along the way.

Comment: I was thinking the same, will keep looking into it. Thanks for your suggestions/help